# Easy-to-use AutoHotkey/AutoIt alternatives for Linux

Tags: linux, user-interface, scripting, automation, autohotkey

I'm looking for recommendations for an easy-to-use GUI automation/macro platform for Linux.

If you're familiar with [AutoHotkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) or [AutoIt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt) on Windows, then you know exactly the kind of features I need, with the level of complexity. If you aren't familiar, then here's a small code snippet of how easy it is to use AutoHotkey:

```
InputBox, varInput, Please enter some random text...
Run, notepad.exe
WinWaitActive, Untitled - Notepad
SendInput, %varInput%
SendInput, !f{Up}{Enter}{Enter}
WinWaitActive, Save
SendInput, SomeRandomFile{Enter}
MsgBox, Your text`, %varInput% has been saved using notepad!

#n::Run, notepad.exe
```

Now the above example, although a bit pointless, is a demo of the sort of functionality and simplicity I'm looking for. Here's an explanation for those who don't speak AutoHotkey:

----Start of Explanation of Code ----

- Asks user to input some text and stores it in varInput
- Runs notepad.exe
- Waits till window exists and is active
- Sends the contents of varInput as a series of keystrokes
- Sends keystrokes to go to File -> Exit
- Waits till the "Save" window is active
- Sends some more keystrokes
- Shows a Message Box with some text and the contents of a variable
- Registers a hotkey, Win+N, which when pressed executes notepad.exe

----End of Explanation----

So as you can understand, the features are quite obvious: Ability to *easily* simulate keyboard and mouse functions, read input, process and display output, execute programs, manipulate windows, register hotkeys, etc. - all being done without requiring any #includes, unnecessary brackets, class declarations, etc. In short: Simple.

Now I've played around a bit with Perl and Python, but it's definitely not AutoHotkey. They're great for more advanced stuff, but surely, there has to be some tool out there for easy GUI automation, right?

PS: I've already tried running AutoHotkey with [Wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29), but sending keystrokes and hotkeys don't work.

Comment: i think that Syngergy+ does this for most platforms including windows and linux, as well as some other things

Comment: Edit: Just to make it clear, I'm not averse to using a language with a well-defined syntax. (I mean, I know how AHK is often associated with novice/noob/non-programmers, but FYI I'm quite comfortable programming in C/C++ and Java)

Comment: @plod: From the website: 

"Synergy+ (synergy-plus) lets you easily share a single mouse and keyboard between multiple computers with different operating systems, without special hardware. All you need is a LAN connection. It's intended for users with multiple computers, where each system uses its own display. It's a little like having a 2nd or a 3rd desktop... "  

Is this the same Synergy+ you're talking about or is there more to it than that description? Because that doesn't sound anything like what I need...

Comment: yes it does do that, but it also allows you to create key bindings that go to one of the computers in its array. I used to use autohotkey to multibox games in the past I have seen people do this using Synergy+. I am not 100% which is why I left you a comment as apposed to an answer.

Comment: Does recommended apps solved the problem ? If so you may consider approving the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Related: [GUI scipting for Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/22896/3474) at SR.SE

Comment: [See also ***AlternativeTo***](https://alternativeto.net/software/autoit/?license=opensource&platform=linux) (*"Crowdsourced software recommendations"*).

Comment: Corresponding question on Ask Ubuntu: *[What is the equivalent tool for AutoIt in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/822075)*

Comment: It's been thirteen years, but [AHK_X11](https://github.com/phil294/AHK_X11) can run the same example script from your question on Linux (except you `Send` instead of `SendInput`)

Answer (score 10):

I'd recommend the site [alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net) to find alternative programs.

It shows three alternatives for AutoIt: AutoKey, Sikuli, and Silktest. [AutoKey](http://alternativeto.net/software/autoit/?platform=linux) seems up to the job.

Comment: `AutoKey` is very handy at handling hotkey-events and has a nice GUI interface. `pyautogui` could be used in conjunction for image/pixel searching, `python-libxdo` for reliable and robust window manipulation and key/mouse simulation, `zenipy` for showing dialogs.

Comment: That page now shows 19 (12 if only open source), in this order: *Sikuli*, *UI.Vision RPA*, *AutoKey*, *Actiona*, *OldAutoKey*, *xdotool*, *TagUI*, *Organize*, *Repeat*, *CloudQA*, *iMacros*, *Testim*, *T-Plan*, *atbswp*, *PhearJS*, *Quikey*, *Xnee**, *Gentee*, and *Silktest*

Answer (score 8):

[**IronAHK**](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=54494) is being developed as a cross-platform flavor of AutoHotkey which can be used on Linux, but it's not a fleshed out product yet.

Comment: Just as a note for people just stumbling upon this, IronAHK is no longer (as of my writing) being worked on, but can be found open source [on git](https://github.com/polyethene/IronAHK).

Comment: If I download the source code, and compile it on Linux, would it work?

Answer (score 5):

[Sikuli](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/) lets you automate your interface using screenshots. It runs on any Java platform, so it is cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [Experitest](http://experitest.com). I'm using the Windows version, but it's Java-based and I think it supports Linux as well.